# Official Facebook iOS app always crashes when calling FB.login() from web app

Tags: javascript, ios, authentication, crash, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've managed to write a simple fiddle that crashes the native iOS facebook app.

If you paste this link into your timeline http://jsfiddle.net/Gc58e/ (it is just a simple button with a FB.login callback with photos scope) and open it from within the native iOS app, it opens in a webview.

### html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="info">Let's see if we can crash it!</div>
    <button class="login">Login with Facebook</button>
</div>
```

### javascript

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '467875209900414'
    });
};
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));

$('.login').on('click', function () {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        alert('login callback' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }, {
        scope: 'user_photos'
    });
});
```

When you click on the button, the authentication window shows and after clicking in either **cancel** or **ok**, the whole application crashes.

It doesn't happen if you are viewing it with Safari directly or in any other browser.

I've seen that many popular apps also crash the when authenticating from the embedded webview inside the native iOS Facebook app; so it might be a bug or just that the correct way of doing it is not evident...

[Here's crashlog](http://pastie.org/7737652).

Comment: I think this should be placed as a bug report, if it wasn't already done so. It is interesting that this is happening

Comment: Facebook have opened an official bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/553867554654664

Comment: there was a bug report; I've linked it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed now by Facebook. I've tested it and seems to work fine.